# 404 error when directly accessing a component or particular page in react js

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-navigation, react-router-dom, custom-error-pages

The problem that I am facing here is, my react js project hosted to a server, everything works fine, i.e. routing, moving the page from top navigation bar etc., But I've observed that when I am closing my website tab and trying to directly access a component or particular page, For example, if I type url "http://mywebsite.com", it works. But if I do "http://mywebsite.com/contact" the page goes 404, and yeah the component does exists. Either approach works well in localhost, but not on the hosted server (Hostinger).

I tried searching over the web, but could not find any reliable answer, many of the posts on StackOverflow say its server related error, but does not show how to fix it.
I have created .htaccess file and paste it in public folder, but that also not work for me.

My router setup is as follows

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
          <Route path="/service" element={<ServicesPage />} />
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: In your local does it works fine and only in hostinger you are not able to access the other pages?

Comment: yes, when accessing from server i can not access "http://mywebsite.com/contact" page directly

Comment: The basic gist is that the server should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into your React app. This is different for each hosting service/server environment. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to gather a sense for what may need to be setup for your specific host. You will also want to check their official documentation as well, they may have instructions.